# navigation bar which has link which scrolls to particular element when clicked

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id='nav'>
<script>
var head={{ head | safe }};
for(let key in head){
var str="<li><a id='1' href='#' onclick='MyFunction(" + key +");'>"+ key +" 
</a></li>"; 
document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML += str;
}
</script>
</ul>
<script>
function MyFunction(key){
console.log(key)
var vv=document.getElementById(key);
vv.scrollIntoView()
vv.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
```

Basically i am trying to make a navigation bar which will navigate a user to the given div element when clicked so if the key matches of div and link by passing function through it then it will scroll to the particular div element.

and the error i am getting is Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: what is `var head={{ head | safe }};` supposed to be doing?

Comment: it converts a python dictionary to a json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your snippet contains server side templating (`{{ head | safe }}`).

What you are asking for can be done using only HTML.
So if you are using server side templating you could just render it like this.
But the point is, even if you render it with Javascript in your browser, you still don't need to use `scrollIntoView()`. If you have an `<a>` element, that has an `href="#id"` where `id` is the element ID of another element on the page, the browser will scroll there.

```css
.spacer {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#entry1">entry1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#entry2">entry2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#entry3">entry3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="entry1">entry1</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="entry2">entry2</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="entry3">entry3</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem ;)